# The autocmd pattern to match filename and part of path in Vim

Tags: vim, autocmd

I am trying to make an auto-cmd triggered by opening a new file with path including `test/` and with filename ending in `Test.java`. Reading in `:h autocmd-patterns` I can not figure out if either only limited patterns can be used as a file pattern in an auto-cmd or if I am simply doing something wrong with my pattern. The following works for matching any file ending in `.java`

```
autocmd! BufNewFile *.java
 \ "command implemented !
```

Now I try to match new files with a path containing `/test/` and with a file name ending in `Test.java` through the following and derivatives of it

```
autocmd! BufNewFile */test/*Test.java
 \ "command implemented !
```

How do I trigger the autocmd on all files having part of their path the `test/` folder and the filename ending in `Test.java`. For instance it should be triggered on doing

```
$ vim code/algos/graphs/test/KruskalTest.java
```

Comment: It's correct, and should work. Works here. Check if the problem isn't within the command you're passing, or try simply `echo "yep"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. When I just used the pattern `*.java` the command triggered correctly. Changing the pattern to */test/*Test.java` made it not get triggered even with an appropriate path. Will look more into VimScript before continuing.

Answer (score 6):

```
augroup MyJavaAUGroup
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.java,*Test.java,*/test/* <<YOURCOMMANDHERE>>
augroup END
```

Comment: This seemed to apply a simple command 3 times when creating a new file with path `code/algos/graphs/test/KruskalTest.java`

Comment: I count 6 conditions that should be met by just opening the file example you just gave with my  `augroup` above. However, please dont misunderstand the usefullness of my example. Please look at the different  `Buf` conditions and also look at the comma seperating the file conditions.

Comment: @JohnKaul "commas" in "autocmd-pattern" stand for alternative not conjunction, so your pattern is weaker and matches more than is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `**/test/*Test.java` pattern instead. Also, ensure that
you chose the correct auto-command event: For the `BufNewFile` event to be
triggered, it is necessary for the file with a given name not to exist.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and report back when I work out what I screwed up in either my .vimrc or ftplugin/java.vim while trying to solve this.